OpenWRT LTE Gateway Setup for Main Router
I can't seem to be able to set up my two involved boxes successfully for the following scenario. The Failover WAN Box should be solely responsible for the Failover WAN. Doble NAT should be avoided.
Main Router:

WAN through FTTH (NAT, FW, DHCP)
LAN (VLANs, several 192.168 subnets)
Failover WAN uplink port (static 10.0.0.222, FW)
Rules for admin access

Failover WAN Box:

WAN through LTE (NAT, DHCP)
LAN (static 10.0.0.1)
Rules for admin access

I have succeeded in letting this run with NAT on the Main Router but the Double NAT prevents some things from working. I have tried to isolate the problems when switching off the NAT on the Main Router and it seems the OpenWRT Failover WAN Box doesn't route properly. I would hope that it understand that the traffic originates from local 192.168 subnets and routes the responses back to the Main Router with its 10.0.0.222 gateway address, for which I have a static route. I presume I'm making mistakes in the field of the Failover WAN Box' FW vs NAT config.
How should I configure the FW and zones on the Failover WAN Box? How do I enable NAT without the FW if it's supposed to be disabled? If its WAN port won't be protected by a FW, how do I protect access to the Failover WAN Box's local services from WAN side? I'm having the impression that the (supposedly simplified) FW setup of OpenWRT may mean something that's different from my understanding.
